# Compare folders recursively using python

Tags: python, algorithm

I'm going to implement recursive folder comparison on python. What do you think would best algorithm for this?

1. Get two lists of the files for the folders
2. Sort both lists
3. Compare using filecmp module for a file
4. Repeat for every folder recursively

In result I need to get only the list of the files that are different (content difference is not needed here), the list of the files that are missing in one of the comparable folders.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Make recursive search over directory and for each file store md5 or sha checksum of file in dictionary as key and  path/name as value. Make this dictionary for both directories. Then you can remove pairs from each directory and result is missing/different files.

This will make simple O(n) algorhitm, where n is volume of directory.

Answer (score 1):

If I was you, I would check if another software doesn't already implement this feature, like `rsync` or `diff`. For what I see, both have the features you need. There are more information about it [here](http://www.unixtutorial.org/2008/06/how-to-compare-directories-in-unix/).

If you really need to do this in Python, I would modify slightly your algorithm, making it look like this:

1. Store both paths contents in two separate list variables using [os.walk](http://docs.python.org/library/os.html#os.walk);
2. Iterate on each value of the first list to find a corresponding value in the second list;
3. If a corresponding value have been found, compare it using the filecmp module. Otherwise, display the missing file;
4. Remove the value from the second list;
5. Go to #2 until the first list is empty;
6. Print everything left in the second list;

Comment: Seems like you would gain some speed by using sets instead of lists.

Comment: What about if I would have the new file in second list but which is missing in first list? According to these steps I would have the same list of files that were initially only in first list. Perhaps you can write here the code example according to the step you listed?